# How to bypass grub user authorization in GNU GRUB

Tags: grub2, root, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a linux machine and I updated the kernel which I shouldnt have done and now the machine won't boot up, I am trying to boot up with a previous kernel from GRUB but the system required me username and password to edit,run anything.
Is there any way to bypass that?
Thank you!

Comment: You're question appears to be about Linux, where SE *Unix & Linux* provides Linux support on Stack Exchange. This is a Ubuntu Q&A site, and I see nothing on-topic for this site (see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic).   GRUB doesn't have usernames so your question itself makes little sense to me, yes an owner of the system can put a *password* on GRUB that is required (*speak to the owner of the machine for that*) but password is not username+password.  FYI:  On-topic systems for this site have *root* disabled; with `sudo` providing access when required.

Comment: When I try to choose for example "Advanced options for ubuntu" it required username and password. We have a line of machines here and I can access different machines that do work with admin user and perform all commands but when I try to insert the same username and password there, it does nothing and goes back to the menu as if the username and password i typed in were incorrect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)